# Display second dropdown list if a value is selected in the first dropdown (using variables)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there any way I can select a certain value in a dropdown list and according to that selection display a second dropdown list?
I know how to do it with just normal words, but what if I use variable names?

```
University Name: <select name="university" id="university">
<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($uniName)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row['uni_name'] . "</option>"; 
    }
?> 
</select>
<br/>
Course Name: <select name='course' id='course'>
<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($courseNames)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row['course_name'] . "</option>"; 
    }
?>
</select>
```

So as you can see, in the first dropdown list I've added all the retrieved university names from my database. I did the same for the courses as well.

Now how can I modify the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#course').hide();

    $('#university').change(function () {
        if ($('#university option:selected').text() == "Harvard University"){
            $('#course').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else { 
            $('#course').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of "Harvard University", I want to put a variable there according to what the user has selected. Something like $university_name and then I'll create a new query and display only the courses belong to a certain $university_name.

Comment: Each university would have an ID, would it not? That's pretty much always better than comparing strings. At the same time, you could check the selected item's index and decide depending on that one. Though, if you want to offer different courses, which depend on the selected university, I recommend doing an AJAX call and fetching the corresponding courses 'onChange'.

Comment: Yes that's right, each uni would have a unique ID. As you said, I want to offer different courses so I'll try use AJAX then. thank you

Comment: If you need help with the setup, be sure to ask.

Comment: If you could suggest any tutorial or an example regarding the AJAX method it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not the PHP, as it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: that's the actual dropdown lists, i just used PHP in order to display the results I retrieved from database. The code I posted above is inside a form and I've put a submit button in the end so I can get the submitted values. I'm not really using any other HTML code apart from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in my comments, I recommend using AJAX to fill the `course` box.

```
$.ajax("getCourses.php", {
    data: { UID: uid },
    type: 'POST',
    done: function(result) {
        $("#course").html(result);
});
```

This will fill the select tags with whatever `getCourses` has for output.

UID would of course be the ID of the university in question.

[This page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has all the info you need. For further information and examples, Google is your friend :)